# In macOS build instructions for Bitcoin Core, why do they recommend creating RPC configuration file?

Tags: bitcoin-core

In this file

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-osx.md

> Before running, it's recommended you create an RPC configuration file.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this suggestion is dates from before cookie authentication existed, and is not needed anymore.

Before, it was impossible to use the RPC protocol to send commands to a running bitcoind/bitcoin-qt instance if no username and password were configured.

Since the introduction of cookie authentication, this is no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Could you, if you have time, do a PR to have that obsolete suggestion removed from the .md file? Otherwise I could do it, but I would refer to your answer here anyway.